# Spark logs to dataframe , create dataframe from the logfiles

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

#Spark #Python

Objective :

Read the location of the log files, extract the csv text table data from the logs and print the json of the table data (Table Columns ( CSV retrieved table columns + serial no + timestamp)

1. Read serial_no, time, s3_path from database
2. s3_path contains csv files.
3. Output needs as a dataframe of the columns in the tables + primary_key + timestamp

Current Code pseudo:

```
df = sparkSession.read \
            .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
            .option("url",
                    "some url with id{}&password={}".format(
                        redshift_user, redshift_pass)) \
            .option("query", query) \
            .option("tempdir", s3_redshift_temp_dir) \
            .option("forward_spark_s3_credentials", True)
            df = df_context.load()
```

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|serial_number|          test_date|             s3_path|
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
|     A0123456|2019-07-10 04:11:52|s3://test-bucket-...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-24 23:48:03|s3://test-bucket-...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 20:56:57|s3://test-bucket-...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 20:56:57|s3://test-bucket-...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 20:58:36|s3://test-bucket-...|
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

Since we cannot pass the spark context to the worker nodes, used boto3 to read the text file and processed the text to fetch the csv table structure.
Not sharing the proprietary code here for retrieving the table from log.

```
spark.udf.register("read_s3_file", read_s3_file)
df_with_string_csv = df.withColumn('files_dataframes', read_s3_file(drive_event_tab.s3_path))
```

df_with_string_csv now contails below sample

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|serial_number|          test_date|             s3_path|    table_csv_data    |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     1050D1BE|2019-05-08 09:26:55|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-25 06:54:28|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:07:21|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:07:21|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-25 00:19:52|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-24 22:24:40|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-09-12 22:15:19|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
|     A0123456|2019-07-22 21:27:56|s3://test-bucket-...|col1,col2,col3,col4...|
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

sample table_csv_data column contains:

```
timestamp,partition,offset,key,value
1625218801350,97,33009,2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP,458969040
1625218801349,41,33018,3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP,17569160
```

Trying to achieve the final dataframe as below, please help

```
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
|serial_number|          test_date|           timestamp|    partition    |  offset   |    key                            |    value     |
+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------+-----------------------------------+--------------+
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11| 1625218801350      |    97           |  33009    | 2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP |  458969040   |
|     1050D1B0|2019-05-07 15:41:11| 1625218801349      |    41           |  33018    | 3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP |  17569160    |               
..
..
..

+-------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spark 2.4.0+ you just need some combinations of split, explode and [array_except](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#array_except)

Please use [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html) to optimize as explode might create a lot of rows.

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, col, array_except, array, trim
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = df \
    .withColumn('table_csv_data', split(col('table_csv_data'), '\n')) \
    .withColumn('table_csv_data', array_except(col('table_csv_data'), array([col('table_csv_data')[0]]))) \
    .withColumn('table_csv_data', explode(col('table_csv_data'))) \
    .withColumn('table_csv_data', split(col('table_csv_data'), ',')) \
    .withColumn('timestamp', trim(col('table_csv_data')[0])) \
    .withColumn('partition', trim(col('table_csv_data')[1])) \
    .withColumn('offset', trim(col('table_csv_data')[2])) \
    .withColumn('key', trim(col('table_csv_data')[3])) \
    .withColumn('value', trim(col('table_csv_data')[4])) \
    .drop('table_csv_data')


df.show(truncate=False)


+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+---------+
|serial_number|test_date          |s3_path          |timestamp    |partition|offset|key                              |value    |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+---------+
|1050D1B0     |2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-|1625218801350|97       |33009 |2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP|458969040|
|1050D1B0     |2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-|1625218801349|41       |33018 |3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP|17569160 |
|1050D1B0     |2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-|1625218801350|97       |33009 |2CKXTKAT_20210701193302_6400_UCMP|458969040|
|1050D1B0     |2019-05-07 15:41:11|s3://test-bucket-|1625218801349|41       |33018 |3FGW9S6T_20210701193210_6400_UCMP|17569160 |
+-------------+-------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------+------+---------------------------------+---------+
```